# Why debugger is not stopping at the breakpoint

Tags: iphone, ios6

I'm trying to debug a point in my app where it will save the image from the imagescrollview to photoalbum based on longpressgesture.

I set a breakpoint in the save photo method.

When I start the application and hit the save photo button it should stop right there but it never stops at the breakpoint  and also not saving photo to photo album

What can I do so that the debugger stops at my breakpoint added?

```
-(void)savePhoto{

CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:_imageView];

if  (CGRectContainsPoint(_imageView.frame, location)){

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_image, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}
}
```

Have a breakpoint at  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum statement. Tried breakpoint at cgpoint location and if statement and breakpoint is stopping at those points but not at  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Appreciate all suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Wait, you say that you set a breakpoint in the save code, then when the image _doesn't actually save_ you wonder why the breakpoint wasn't hit? Maybe it's not running that code at all.

Comment: but when i set breakpoint at CGPoint and at if CGRectContainsPoint it does stop at those two statements

Comment: Well, if it runs the code right before the conditional, and the conditional itself, but not the code inside the conditional.. maybe the conditional is evaluating to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the if condition evaluates to false

Add a log before the if statement to check if it evaluates to 0 or 1

```
NSLog(@"contains point?? - %d", CGRectContainsPoint(_imageView.frame, location));
```

Comment: but how can i fix this. i think it is not able to read _image

Comment: You probably want to check _imageView's bounds, not frame, since your point is the location inside _imageView already.

Comment: when i say bounds it contains 1 but then it is saving the very last image but not the one which i selected